# Find all sets of strongly-connected vertices

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

I have a linked-list of edges to a digraph which I am trying to find all sets of strongly-connected components. Can anybody point me toward an algorithm with a good worst-case time (sample pseudo or C code would be much appreciated).

**EDIT:** I am trying to find all sets of edges that create strongly-connected components and not the vertices. In the graph below notice that there are 2 sets of edges to create a strongly-connected component, however only two edges on the graph are used for both (a->b and b->c). The algorithm should be able to produce sets { a->b, b->c, c->a } and { a->b, b->c, c->b, b->a }.

http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/8025/digraph.jpg

Hope that helps make more clear my goal.

**EDIT2:** I have a semi working implementation, however I noticed that it doesn't work if the graph which I am searching in is also strongly connected. Does anybody know of a way to find SCC within a SCC?

Comment: I've extended my answer to record edges too

Answer (score 3):

The [Strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) definition on wikipedia recommends three algorithms. I would go with [Tarjan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) as the best combination of efficiency and ease of implementation.

I've taken the Pseudo-code on wikipedia, and modified to keep a list of all SCCs. It follows:

```
Input: Graph G = (V, E)

List<Set> result = empty
index = 0                                   // DFS node number counter 
S = empty                                   // An empty stack of nodes
for all v in V do
  if (v.index is undefined)                 // Start a DFS at each node
    tarjan(v, result)                       // we haven't visited yet

procedure tarjan(v, result)
  v.index = index                           // Set the depth index for v
  v.lowlink = index                               
  index = index + 1
  S.push(v)                                 // Push v on the stack
  for all (v, v2) in E do                   // Consider successors of v
    if (v2.index is undefined)              // Was successor v' visited?
      tarjan(v2, result)                    // Recurse
      v.lowlink = min(v.lowlink, v2.lowlink)
    else if (v2 is in S)                   // Was successor v' in stack S? 
      v.lowlink = min(v.lowlink, v2.index) // v' is in stack but not the dfs tree
  if (v.lowlink == v.index)                // Is v the root of an SCC?
    set interconnected = empty
    previous = v
    repeat
      v2 = S.pop                                  
      interconnected.add((previous,v2)) // record this edge
      last = previous=v2
    until (v2 == v)
    result.add(interconnected)
```

---

*Edit in response to further specification.*
Do you see that the algorithm pushes the vertices onto the stack then pops them off again? I think this probably means that you can know that each consecutive stack element is connected to the one before by an edge. I've modified the pseudo-code above to reflect this, (but haven't tried it).

Comment: I don't believe the stack of vertices are ordered correctly for that to work, I tried before posting the question. I would think that the stack would be somewhat ordered by the "depth" of the vertex. I wonder if the algorithm can be converted to a BFS (and if that would do any good).

Comment: if the nodes are strongly connected then the start point doesn't matter, they are a loop. Or have I missed something. What ordering do you require?

Comment: Nick, if you look at the image in the link I posted. You will see that the graph itself is strongly connected. I don't believe Tarjan's will work for finding SCC if the graph is strongly connected.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page for [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) points to three algorithms, all of them explained in wikipedia in sufficient detail to directly translate into source code. If that information is insufficient, you probably should indicate what exactly is missing.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear from the entires in wikipedia if any of algorithms would produce an exhaustive list of all SCCs. So before implementing, I figured I should ask.

Comment: In the wikipedia page for tarjan http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_strongly_connected_components_algorithm it is recursive, where it says "print SCC:" you should add the vertex to your result list of SCCs.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it is fairly trivial to add the vertex to a linked-list containing my results. However, I wonder if anybody can provide a modification to store the edges instead of the vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Even after your second edit, I'm still not sure what your goal actually is.  This is hindered by your choice of terminology.  SCCs as most people mean them are maximal sets of vertices that are all reachable from each other, and what paths may occur simply doesn't matter.

> Does anybody know of a way to find SCC within a SCC?

By the usual definitions, there is no such thing as an SCC within an SCC, because an SCC is maximal.

You're looking for something else: you start with a connected graph, and want to find particular edge sets that you have not well characterized. I strongly suspect that if you do characterize what you want in a clear way, an algorithm will fall out.

My first guess, was that for a given connected graph, you want the edge sets of all possible combinations of all paths connecting each pair.  If that's the case, the straightforward way to do this is: for each pair, find all paths, then find all combinations and eliminate duplicates.  However, this generates more sets than you list in your example, as using all of the edges is certainly possible.

Instead, it appears you want all *minimal* edge sets that still let the original vertices remain an SCC.  In this case, each element of the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the original edge set represents a possible candidate, and you want all of the candidates where the graph is still connected, but with no proper subset that is still connected.

This gives a straightforward algorithm of walking this lattice of sets and checking this condition.  Checking if a graph is connected is straight-forward, as is removing or adding edges.  However, similar graphs have most of the same structure, so you'll want to reuse what you can from previous problems.

Some references that may help:

- [Connectivity (graph theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29)
- [Menger's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem)
- [Max-flow min-cut theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)

Especially in terms of connecting global information of the graph to local information about edges and vertices.

---

Your starting graph G has a set of vertices V, and Edges E, and is strongly connected.
The goal is to output all "minimal" sets of edges E' such that removing any edge from E breaks the graph into multiple SCCs.  We can do this by searching all possible edgesets.

Straightforwardly this is:

```
for E' in powerset(E):
    if (V, E') strongly connected:
        for e in E':
            if (V, E' - e) strongly connected:
                 try next E' # Not minimal
        add G' = (V, E') to list of minimal subsets.
```

However this is incredibly wasteful: Obviously unconnected graphs are
tested, and the connectivity of each graph is tested many many times.
We can eliminate the first by searching through the possible edgesets
in a much nicer order, arranging these edge sets in a lattice.  Each
edgeset has "direct children" given by that edgeset minus one edge.
Once we run into a graph that is not an SCC, we need not check any of
its subsets, as they can't be SCCs either.  The easiest way to express
this is as a graph search.  While a depth first search is often the
way to go, as it uses less memory, I'm going to choose a breadth first
search, because later on we will use the order of traversal.  (A depth
first search changes the queue to a stack).

```
push starting node on queue
while queue not empty:
    pop node from queue
    for c in suitable children, not on queue:
        push c on queue
    deal with node
```

The "not on queue" part is crucial, otherwise each node can be visited
many times.  This turns our algorithm into:

```
push E on queue
while queue not empty:
    pop E' from queue
    if (V, E') strongly connected:
        minimal = true
        for e in E':
            if (V, E' - e) strongly connected:
                push E' - e on queue if not on queue
                minimal = false           
        if minimal:
            add G' = (V, E') to list of minimal subsets.
```

Now it skips all the edgesets that can't possibly be strongly connected,
because supersets aren't either.  The downside is that it can
possibly use lots of space. It still, however, repeatedly checks for
connectivity.  We can, however, *cache* that information.

```
check_or_add_cached_connected(E)
push E on queue
while queue not empty:
    pop E' from queue
    connected = cached (E')
    if connected:
        minimal = true
        for e in E':
            child_connected = check_or_add_cache(E' - e)
            if child_connected:
                push E' - e on queue if not on queue
                minimal = false
        if minimal:
            add G' = (V, E') to list of minimal subsets.
    remove E' from cache
```

Now that we've started caching, there's more we could cache.  If
removing an edge breaks the graph, it will also break any subgraph.
This means we can keep track of "required edges" in a graph and
propagate them down to any subgraph.  And we can check these required
edges to avoid checking subgraphs.

```
check_or_add_cached_connected(E)
push E on queue
while queue not empty:
    pop E' from queue
    (connected, required_edges) = cached (E')
    if connected:
        minimal = true
        for e in E' and not in required_edges:
            child_connected = check_or_add_cached_connected(E' - e)
            if child_connected:
                push E' - e on queue if not on queue
                minimal = false
            else:
                add e to required_edges
        if minimal:
            add G' = (V, E') to list of minimal subsets.
        else:
            for e in E' and not in required_edges:
                merge_cache(E' - e, required_edges)
    remove E' from cache
```

The structure of the cache and queue do require a bit of work to ensure the operations used can be done efficiently, but this is fairly straightforward.

Comment: This is the best answer yet. And thank you for correcting me, I wasn't aware that an SCC is always the maximum number of vertices. Also, you are correct, I want to find the minimal cost of edges for the set to remain strongly-connected. Can you explain your "straightforward" algorithm please, with maybe some links or pseudo code?

Comment: @Joe Boo: Wait, I thought you wanted to find all minimal sets, not just the minimal cost one.  I'll try to expand my answer a bit later.